# view.getMeasuredHeight() is returning value as 0 for a view with height more than 0

Tags: android, android-layout

I have written following code snippet. At first line height is non zero but after calculating height using view.measure, it is returning height as zero.

This view is a linear layout with no child and height set using dynamic code.

```
 int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
 view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
  height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: it is the expected behaviour

Comment: Does it mean, if height is non  zero then I should call view.measure method. sometime height is getting returned as very small and after view.measure it is returning correct height. Please guide me that what should be the correct implementation to fetch view height

Comment: does it mean, if the container is empty, why do you expect is going to have a height

Comment: I am implementing header animation, for that my list view should start below header. We are creating one empty view with the height same as header